# Angular 9 - typeform embed: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react'

Tags: angular, embed, angular9, typeform

I'm trying to integrate typeform embed it with an angular 9 project.

I've installed typeform using NPM I referred to this https://developer.typeform.com/embed/

```
npm install --save @typeform/embed
```

then in my component.ts file I tried to test it.

```
import * as typeformEmbed from '@typeform/embed';

export class MyComponent {
  ...
  initTypeform() {
    console.log(typeformEmbed)
  }
}
```

in my terminal I get this error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react' in '/app/node_modules/@typeform/embed/build'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@typeform/embed/build/lib.pure.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-dom' in '/app/node_modules/@typeform/embed/build'
```

Answer (score 1):

so I was able to make it work by installing react & react-dom to my Angular 9 project dependencies.

```
npm i react
```

&

```
npm i react-dom
```